# Solving $\log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)}= 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve this equation:
$$\log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)}= 2$$

I'd like some advice on what to go about it, so far I have made it into:

$$\begin{aligned}\log_3(x)\cdot\log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)=2
\\\log_3(x)\cdot\log_x(\log_4(x))-\log_x(\log_4(x)-3)=2\end{aligned}$$

And I'm unsure how to proceed from here?

Comment: Is $log_3(x)$ the exponent if the argument of the base $x$ logarithm?

Comment: Hey yes that's correct, the steps I've done so far aren't necessarily the right ways to go

Comment: I would use change of base on all the logarithms to natural log(or log 2 if you want) and then just combine them all and repeatedly take e^(or 2^) of both sides. Also, WA claims $x=64 \cdot 2^{3/4}$ is the solution so looks like stuff should simplify or at least be nice.

Comment: Use $\log_a b\cdot \log_b c=\log_a c$

Comment: @mintteaplease, please read my answer and tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using change of base rule:

$\log_3(x)= \frac{\log(x)}{\log(3)};$
$\log_4(x)= \frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)};$
$\log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)=\frac{\log\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)}{\log(x)}$

$2= \log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)}=  \log_3(x)\cdot\log_x\left(\frac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)=
$
$\begin{aligned}= \frac{\log\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)}-3\right)}\right)}{\log(x)} \frac{\log(x)}{\log(3)}&=2\\
\implies \log\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)}-3\right)}\right)&=2 \log(3)=\log(9)\end{aligned}$

Then $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(4)}-3\right)}=9.$

Now, isolate $\log(x)$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit unsure how you converted my function to the first expression, or how the change of base rule should be applied here, do you mind breaking it down a bit?

Comment: @mintteaplease the change of base rule suggests that $log_{3}(x) = \frac{log(x)}{log(3)}$. Same for that other huge scarry logarithm with base $x$

Comment: @mintteaplease I made an edit with full details in case it's still hard to grasp

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve your equation, it is sufficient to use the definition of logarithm and the property $\,\log_b(a)=\dfrac1{\log_a(b)}\,.$

Since $\,\log_x\!\left(\!\dfrac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\!\right)^{\!\log_3(x)}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=2\;,\;$ by definition of logarithm

$\log_x(\cdot)\,,\,$ it follows that

$x^2=\left(\dfrac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)}\;.$

Moreover,

$x^{2\log_x(3)}=\left(\dfrac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)\cdot\log_x(3)}\;,$

$\left(x^{\log_x(3)}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\right)^{\log_3(x)\cdot\frac1{\log_3(x)}}\;,$

$3^2=\dfrac{\log_4(x)}{\log_4(x)-3}\;\;,$

$\log_4(x)=\dfrac{27}8\;\;,$

$x=4^{\frac{27}8}=2^{\frac{27}4}=64\sqrt[4]8\;.$